# recieve object type by argument

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to pass object type by argument, and i couldn't find any way to do that.

this is what i've tried so far:

I'm trying to do a generic function for multiple classes (int, double etc.)

```
void changeObject(class this)
{
    static_cast<this&>(object[0][0]).foo()
}
```

but I couldn't make it work, this is not for H\W, but instead a project i'm work on.

Comment: You can't pass types as arguments. What are you really trying to do? What is the actual and underlying problem you try to solve? Why do you think you need to pass a type as argument? Please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), then [edit] your question to ask about the actual problem you try to solve instead.

Comment: Types are determined at compile-time (and are not values; `class` is not a type). There are almost certainly ways to solve your actual problem, or even make it go away, so post a question about that problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to make `changeObject()` be a [template function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates), eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void changeObject()
{
    static_cast<T&>(object[0][0]).foo();
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```cpp
changeObject<DesiredTypeHere>();
```